# CSS Animation doesn't work with inline display property?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

As the title says, my CSS Animation doesn't work properly with the `display: inline` property...What am I doing wrong here?

I have narrowed it down to this bit of css code provided below that is giving me the troubles.  If I provide all the code, it would literally take forever to look through as it's quite lengthy - however, if you need more let me know.

Anyway, in the HTML part, I have the class `navcontent` with `style="display: none;"` which looks like this:  `<div id="all" class="navcontent" style="display: none;"></div>`

I need that bit of html to be hidden as the navcontent class also acts as tabs that once you click upon, the data/content within will appear in a specific container that's fixed (which any tab clicked the data/content appears/disappears in the same specific container)...

So with that being said, I have also applied some animation to that specific container but am having troubles making the animation work with display: inline...

Without the display: inline, the animation works great, but if you click on another tab, the content that is supposed to appear - isn't there.  So I guess you can say I'm in a catch22 situation...

With the display: inline, the animation doesn't work, BUT the tabs work and appear like they should.

CSS:

```
.navcontent ul {
  width: 554px;
  height: 299px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
    -moz-perspective: 400px;
    -webkit-perspective: 400px;
    -ms-perspective: 400px;
    -o-perspective: 400px;
    perspective: 400px;
  position: relative;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  z-index: 9997;
}
.navcontent ul li {
  width: 536px;
  height: 140px;
  margin: 5px auto 10px auto;
  /* display: inline; */ /* Issues - If display is off, works as intended but other tabs do not show up at all if clicked.  If display is enabled, animation doesn't work... */
    -moz-transform: translateZ(0);
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
    -ms-transform: translateZ(0);
    -o-transform: translateZ(0);
    transform: translateZ(0);
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}
.navcontent ul li:nth-child(odd) {
  background: rgba(204, 204, 204, 0.07);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(transparent, rgba(204, 204, 204, 0.07));
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(transparent), to(rgba(204, 204, 204, 0.07)));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(transparent, rgba(204, 204, 204, 0.07));
    background: -o-linear-gradient(transparent, rgba(204, 204, 204, 0.07));
}
```

Any Ideas -or- thoughts?

UPDATE:

JS

```
$(function () {
    $('#options ul li a').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
            return;
        } else {
            var currentitm = $('#options ul li a.active').attr('id');
            if (currentitm == 'division_all_link') {
                var currentlist = $('#division_all');
            }
            if (currentitm == 'division_latest_link') {
                var currentlist = $('#division_latest');
            }
            if (currentitm == 'division_featured_link') {
                var currentlist = $('#division_featured');
            }
            if (currentitm == 'division_popular_link') {
                var currentlist = $('#division_popular');
            }

            var newitm = $(this).attr('id');
            if (newitm == 'division_all_link') {
                var newlist = $('#division_all');
            }
            if (newitm == 'division_latest_link') {
                var newlist = $('#division_latest');
            }
            if (newitm == 'division_featured_link') {
                var newlist = $('#division_featured');
            }
            if (newitm == 'division_popular_link') {
                var newlist = $('#division_popular');
            }

            $('#options ul li a').removeClass('active');
            $(this).addClass('active');
            $(currentlist).fadeOut(320, function () {
                $(newlist).fadeIn(200);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 5):

You **cannot** transform elements with `display: inline;` - use inline-block instead:

```
.navcontent ul li {
    display: inline-block;
   /* .. */
    transform: translateZ(0);
}
```

This is stated clearly in the related [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-transforms-1/):

**transformable element**

> A transformable element is an element in one of these categories:
>
> an element whose layout is governed by the CSS box model which is
>   either a block-level or atomic inline-level element, or whose display
>   property computes to table-row, table-row-group, table-header-group,
>   table-footer-group, table-cell, or table-caption [CSS21]
>
> an element in
>   the SVG namespace and not governed by the CSS box model which has the
>   attributes transform, ‘patternTransform‘ or gradientTransform [SVG11].

Note that *atomic inline-level element* is referring to `inline-block`

Comment: using `inline-block` allows me to see the animation now, but am running into the issue of the other tabs (once clicked) the content on that specific container doesn't show up...

Comment: Can you send a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) link? It's hard to help without seeing all code or a demo.

Comment: It's in the Divisions container.  As you will note, the animation works as of right now, however, if you click on the options tab in the upper left hand corner and select the tab "Latest" and then try scrolling down, the content within disappears...

Comment: @user2732875: I see it now. Give me a moment.

Comment: But if I put `display: inline` in there, the content within each tab works as it should - only issue is that the animation doesn't work if implemented...

Comment: @user2732875: Because the `transform` is no longer in effect when it has `display: inline;`

Comment: There is a lot going on here - are you sure the JS script you're using is configured correctly? I noticed the `past` class isn't being added when you scroll under latest.

Comment: As far as I know all that is on my JS scripts works and should be configured correctly.  The animation is strictly being called from the bit of css I have designated for it.  The past class should be for when you scroll back up giving it that effect - the future class should be the opposite (for when you scroll downwards to get that effect)...The only thing I can think of is to restructure that container a bit - perhaps creating a separate div holder which will allow the animation to work?

Comment: @user2732875: Without knowing more about the JS it's hard for to me help further. But if you restructure things and run into an issue I'll gladly take a look.

Comment: I have updated my original post which includes the JS that allows the tab switching